# MySQL broke; how can I save some of the tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

For some reason my MySQL can't connect any more. I'm running three WordPress sites and I need to save the tables. That's what I really really really really care about.

Here is the problem:

> root@dev:/var/log/mysql# mysql ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect
>   to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

The same error is displayed when logging in with phpMyAdmin..

All of the websites display this error:

> Error establishing a database connection

Comment: Where is this hosted?

Comment: Have you tried restarting MySQL?  You might have just run out of sockets because of a DDOS attack.

Comment: At linode in NJ

Comment: mysql server is down... database files should not be deleted, if they are deleted or corrupted check binlogs, you can recover db from binlogs if enabled

Comment: Shut down your web server, and try restarting MySQL server.  Probably everything is fine.  If not, aren't you glad you take daily backups?

Answer (score 7):

mysql is not running - why don't you try starting it

And of course none of this should be a real issue because you have regular backups right?

Comment: What if he isn't an admin?

Comment: I think the answer to that is obvious

Comment: linode's business grants ssh access to customers.  If the original questioner isn't an admin, he surely has a colleague who is.